# corralte subquery in linq

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008

convert this sqlserver corralate subquery to linq -

```
 SELECT 
   ET2.[OID],       
   ET2.[EID],
   ET2.[OrID],  
   ET2.ValidFromDate,
   ET2.Quantity,
   ET2.RAQID,
   ET2.Threshold
 FROM 
   [CDev].[Inf].[FEThreshold] AS ET2 
 WHERE     
   ET2.ValidFromDate = 
   (
      SELECT 
         MAX(ET1.ValidFromDate)
      FROM    
         [CDev].[Inf].[FEThreshold] AS ET1    
      WHERE
         ET1.OID = ET2.OID   
         AND ET1.EID = ET2.EID 
         AND ET1.OrID  = ET2.OrID
   )
```

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala: seems like no good answers received for the previous ones

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, he asked 7 questions, atleast one also not recieved good answers??? I dont think so.

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala: Yes may be. But there are some situation like this as well **http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126536/what-if-all-answers-to-my-question-are-bad** :)

Comment: Ok, i agree with it. But I said him to accept it they help that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result= 
      (
        from ET2 in db.FEThreshold
        where
            ET2.ValidFromDate=
            (
                from ET1 in db.FEThreshold
                where ET1.OID == ET2.OID   
                && ET1.EID == ET2.EID 
                && ET1.OrID == ET2.OrID
                select ET1.ValidFromDate
            ).Max()
        select new
        {
            ET2.OID,       
            ET2.EID,
            ET2.OrID,  
            ET2.ValidFromDate,
            ET2.Quantity,
            ET2.RAQID,
            ET2.Threshold
        }
    );
```